# Forward biasing a diode past built-in voltage

Tags: diodes

Why can't we forward biase a diode past its built-in voltage/potential? What's the problem in doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you increase the voltage across the forward-biased diode, the current increases *exponentially*, as does power dissipation in the diode. Eventually this exceeds the thermal capacity of the diode. This kills the diode.

$$I = I_s\Big(e^{\frac{V_D}{nV_T}}-1\Big)$$

where

```
I is the diode current,
IS is the reverse bias saturation current (or scale current),
VD is the voltage across the diode,
VT is the thermal voltage, and
n is the ideality factor
```

Comment: Good, At any high current you'd want to include a series resistance also.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Yes, ohmic resistance will come strongly into play at high currents. For a 1N4148 it's around 1\$\Omega\$.

Answer (score 3):

I like to liken a diode to the wall of a dam.  You can fill up the water behind the wall up to the height of the dam, but once you reach that level *(the forward voltage)* the water flows over the top so it stays at that level.  Current literally flows :)

The only way to get the water higher than the level of the dam is to flood the land beyond the dam also to the same level, in which case there won't actually be any current flow since there's no difference in levels.

This site has a good description of it: http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/Diode%20-%20How%20A%20Diode%20Works/How%20A%20Diode%20Works.html

Comment: Or to push so much water through the system that the water has to rise before it can drain fast enough.

Comment: In which case the wall collapses under the weight of the water.

Comment: Yep. (to clarify, I meant so much water that the water has to rise a bit over the top of the dam)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at a typical rectifier - the 1N4007 ([datasheet](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds28002.pdf)). Look at figure 2, which shows voltage vs. current. Consider how the current increases with voltage. And let's also calculate the power which the diode dissipates for each case (which is just the product of voltage times current).

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{volts} & \text{amps} & \text{watts} \\ 
\hline
0.7 & 0.01 & 0.007 \\
0.8 & 0.1 & 0.08 \\
0.9 & 0.7 & 0.63 \\
1.0 & 2.0 & 2.0 \\
1.1 & 3.5 & 3.85 \\
1.2 & 5.5 & 6.6 \\
1.3 & 7.5 & 9.75 \\
1.4 & 10 & 14 \\
\end{array}
$$

You'll notice that you can indeed get more voltage than the diode voltage (~0.7 volts) but it takes more and more current to get even fairly small increases in voltage. Plus, of course, the diode can only handle a certain amount of power before it bursts into flames (or better yet, explodes). Since the 1N4007 used for this example is rated for 1 watt continuous, trying to get a continuous voltage of more than about 0.9 volts will cause it to fail.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't we forward bias a diode past its built-in
>   voltage/potential? What's the problem in doing so?

No problems doing so at all - precision op-amp rectifiers do this to obtain what is virtually the rectification properties of an ideal diode: -

[image]

Here the op-amp's output finds whatever level is necessary to forward bias the diode sufficiently to obtain signal rectification of Vi.

Comment: But this increases the potential drop across the diode *to* its forward voltage, not (significantly) *past*

Comment: It forward biases the diode to the exact amount to pass precisely thye positive half of a sinewave. I do not claim it does anything else.